# Simple web crawler on android?

Tags: java, eclipse

Configuration : Eclipse for Android Developper - jre1.7 - Windows 8 (:s) -

I am developing a small application on Android. In the moment, I would like just print my website on the MainActivity. I've really tried to realize it with stackoverflow and my patience and I'm falling on the following source code :

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.io.Reader; 
import java.util.HashSet; 
import java.util.Set; 
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse; 
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException; 
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient; 

public class Crawler {



            public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            crawlPage("http://www.google.com/");
        }       

                       private static void crawlPage(String string) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }

        static Set<String checked = new HashSet<String();

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")         private static void main(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

            if (checked.contains(url))
                return;

            checked.add(url);

            System.out.println("Crawling: " + url);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.bratiska.wordpress.com");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            Reader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());


                String link="";
                new ParserDelegator().parse(reader, link, true);

                if (link.startsWith("http://www.libnum.fr"))
                        crawlPage(link);

            } finally {
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
      } 
}
```

Need help for the `private static void crawlPage()` method !

Comment: what seems to be the problem with it?

Comment: this does not have anything to do with Android

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: @Ahmed Aeon Axan I want the result to an Android application. It's important for me !

Comment: If I call Crawler in my MainActivity, do you think it print the bratiska.wordpress.com website ?

Comment: The `crawlPage` method isn't doing anything at all... try correcting your code and remove those static void main methods. These are for use with standard `Java` and has nothing to do inside code that are used in an `Android` application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this supposed to be an Android application? If so, maybe start off by putting some of this code into an Activity. Most Android apps start from some sort of Activity or are a Service of some sort. From there maybe put the web request in an AsyncTask unless Thread violations are not an issue but the main function makes me think this is written for Java and not Android. The crawl page method should just read the input stream into a StringBuilder and write the text received to a TextView? You have to give us some more to go on. Maybe start off by putting this into an Android application and we can help out some more from there.

Comment: Thanks Sean ! So my new question is for a crawlPage method in Java.

Comment: Thank you for approving my answer. I do not have as high of a rating on here as I would imagine one might have. I am imagineing that your web crawler s just going to read the text off a web page? That would be done with some simple examples that are on here. If you need help with that I can post how to do it in another answer.