# Replicating a website for offline use

Tags: android, webview

I am showing a website within a WebView in an Android app. Since this is a particular page which my app has to access frequently, I would like to offer a cached version of it for when the user has no connectivity. So if the user has an internet connection, the website would be accessed from the internet and a copy would be made. IF you access again but have no connectivity, the cached version should be shown.

My app is for API version 9 and above.

My question is, how would you go and download all assets from a particular page?

Answer (score 1):

The webview is already doing that for you once the user visits that view. The page is loaded and cached. You can set the webview to cache on the sd card like this:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

[link to docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK)

If this default behaviour isn't enough for you you can look into fetching the content with a httpclient and storing that information. But then you'll have to adapt your webview to go look there first and you'll have to make sure you download all the resources that webpage needs.

Comment: How sure can I be that it will cache it by itself and keep the copy there, at least until my app is uninstalled or its data is wiped?

Comment: I second your concerns, @MichelReap, from my experience, this doesn't work as advertised.

Answer (score 1):

So these are two questions you are asking. The one bit regarding WebView and cache was already answered.

Regarding this bit "My question is, how would you go and download all assets from a particular page?", check these links :

- [How to create web crawler in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131153/how-to-create-web-crawler-in-java)
- [Simple web crawler on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338706/simple-web-crawler-on-android)
- [How to save file from website to sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472226/how-to-save-file-from-website-to-sdcard)

First link is a crawler implementation in Java, the second link is basically that code being used (somewhat badly) on Android, the third link should give you enough info as how to download files.

Hope this helps

Comment: So basically I should go brute-force and manually download all elements by myself? Isn't there a working solution already, like API 11's webView.saveWebArchive() ?

Comment: The working solution is the one provided by hcpl before. You can tweak with the cache settings by doing the `getSettings()` on the WebView  [WebSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) , and that is usually enough. If this does not suite your needs, then yeah, I believe you have to write your code do do specifically what you think you want unless there is a lib around somewhere that does the crawling for you